# Firefox extensions & XUL: get page source code

Tags: javascript, xul, firefox-addon, innerhtml

I am developing my first Firefox extension and for that I need to get the complete source code of the current page. How can I do that with XUL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

really looks like there is no way to get "all the sourcecode". You may use

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

to get the innerHTML of the top element (usually html). If you have a php error message like

```
<h3>fatal error</h3>
segfault

<html>
    <head>
        <title>bla</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

the innerHTML would be

```
<head>
<title>bla</title></head><body><h3>fatal error</h3>
segfault    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
        </script></body>
```

but the error message would still retain

edit: documentElement is described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.documentElement

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for. However, I don't understand the example code you posted. Is the second block supposed to be the text printed via `alert` in the first block? If so, why would the error message suddenly appear inside the `body` tag?

Comment: yep, the second code block was the code being alerted. Thats probably firefox's code correction. Just copy the first block into an empty html-file and try it out :-)

Comment: This is not the complete source. As you noted, everything that's not between `<html>` and `</html>` doesn't get included. Lachlan's answer seems to be a much better solution.

Answer (score 6):

You will need a xul [browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser) object to load the content into.

Load the "view-source:" version of your page into a the browser object, in the same way as the "View Page Source" menu does. See function viewSource() in `chrome://global/content/viewSource.js`. That function can load from cache, or not.

Once the content is loaded, the original source is given by:

```
var source = browser.contentDocument.getElementById('viewsource').textContent;
```

**Serialize a DOM Document**
This method will not get the original source, but may be useful to some readers.

You can serialize the document object to a string. See [Serializing DOM trees to strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_and_serializing_XML#section_1) in the MDC. You may need to use the alternate method of instantiation in your extension.

That article talks about XML documents, but it also works on any HTML DOMDocument.

```
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var source = serializer.serializeToString(document);
```

This even works in a web page or the firebug console.

Comment: This looks pretty complete, too. What happens if the XHTML is broken due to some error, though?

Comment: The DOM parser will already have dealt with broken HTML, so seriaizer will not see the broken source.

Comment: That would probably be bad then? Does the `document` variable have the property `textContent`, too?

Comment: Your edit looks veeery interesting. If this works out, this should be it.

Comment: Haven't yet had time to check. I will do so, though, before the bounty runs out. Don't worry ;)

Comment: I feel really stupid now. I can't get the browser class to work. How can I create that kind of object?

Comment: "view source" creates it via XUL, see 'chrome://global/content/viewSource.xul'

Comment: I'm experimenting with this solution and it seems to be working perfectly so far! Thank you Lachlan! @Franz I would think that creating a new one (`document.createElement('browser')`) should work, but you can also just put it in your main overlay XUL: `<browser id="invisibleBrowser" collapsed="true"/> <!-- This is never actually shown. It's just used for getting the raw source of HTML pages -->` and then of course, in your js file: `var browser = document.getElementById('invisibleBrowser')`

Answer (score 2):

You can get URL with `var URL = document.location.href` and navigate to `"view-source:"+URL`.

Now you can fetch the whole source code (viewsource is the id of the body):

```
var code = document.getElementById('viewsource').innerHTML;
```

Problem is that the source code is formatted. So you have to run [strip_tags](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags:535)() and [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars_decode:427)() to fix it.

For example, line 1 should be the doctype and line 2 should look like:

```
&lt;<span class="start-tag">HTML</span>&gt;
```

So after [strip_tags](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags:535)() it becomes:

```
&lt;HTML&gt;
```

And after [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars_decode:427)() we finally get expected result:

```
<HTML>
```

The code doesn't pass to DOM parser so you can view invalid HTML too.

Comment: Hmmm... sounds pretty good. Is the entire code wrapped in an element with ID `viewsource` or why are you doing it that way? And what do you mean by "formatted"? Are the entities escaped?

Comment: Think of it as a normal HTML code. The body id is viewsource. I've added example how it looks. I hope that you have some ideas how to go this page (you can do it with hidden iframe, for example).

Comment: Or you could just use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: Franz: You don't need all of that. Just use `document.getElementById('viewsource').textContent`

Comment: @Eli Grey - Thanks. I verified and it works. However, comments are striped.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then that you can choose.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get it via DOM, using

> var source =document.getElementsByTagName("html");

and fetch the source using DOMParser

> https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOMParser

Comment: getElementsByTagName (note: elements)

Answer (score 0):

The first part of Sagi's answer, but use `document.getElementById('viewsource').textContent` instead.

Answer (score 0):

More in line with Lachlan's answer, but there is a discussion of the internals here that gets quite in depth, going into the Cpp code.

http://www.mail-archive.com/mozilla-embedding@mozilla.org/msg05391.html

and then follow the replies at the bottom.